# I want to make div for class "BLACK" which doesn't resize on resizing browser

Tags: html, css, resize, size, height

how to make a div which do not resize with browser resize?
div for that code is as below there are other 7 classes same as purple but I want BLACK not to resize with browser what are possible steps I can look for

```
<div class="BLACK">
    <P>THIS IS BLACK DIV AND IT WILL NOT RESIZE WITH 
       BROWSER</P>
</div>
<div class="PURPLE">
    <p>THIS IS PURPLE DIV AND IT WILL RESIZE WITH BROWSER</p>
</div>


.BLACK
{
    background-color: black;
    background-size: contain;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: fixed;
    height:20%;
    width:20%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 30%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding-top: 9%;
    padding-bottom: 8%;
}

.PURPLE
{
    background-color: purple;
    height: 7%;
    padding-top: 0.05%;
    padding-bottom: 0.05%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Decide what size you want it to be in px units for example and use those instead of the % values in the settings for .BLACK

Answer (score 2):

`div` size can be fixed using px unit like `width:20px;` or `width:300px;`

```html
<div class="BLACK">
  <p>THIS IS BLACK DIV AND IT WILL NOT RESIZE WITH BROWSER</p>
</div>
<div class="PURPLE">
  <p>THIS IS PURPLE DIV AND IT WILL RESIZE WITH BROWSER</p>
</div>
```

```css
.BLACK {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  width: 350px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-top: 9%;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
}

.PURPLE {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 7%;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 0.05%;
  padding-bottom: 0.05%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
```